# Bootstrap tooltip vs normal HTML title

Tags: html, tooltip

I'm going to add a lot of tooltips to my web site in order to guide the visitor.

I can do this easily with the HTML title-attribute. But I can also use the Bootstrap's tooltip plugin (this requires an extra data-toggle-attribute for each tooltip though).

Is there any obvious reason why I should *avoid* using the easier HTML title-tag only?

I'm not interesting in positioning and layout of the tooltip. I simply want to show the text.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is a front-end framework that just have pre-made css classes to make things easier with a predefined style etc. It's your own choice if you want these styles (which requires less work from your part) or you can implement it on your own. If style doesn't bother you, you can easily go with the title attribute for html. But otherwise I suggest you use something like bootstrap. It's just personal preference.

You can also make changes to these predefined styles by adding a stylesheet after the bootstrap.min.css. It still requires less work from you.

Answer (score 1):

Since that you're only interested in showing the text you probably should go for HTML title attribute but to be sure, ask yourself if the text has a any meaning, semantic meaning, if yes, use Title attribute if not (and it's there to make the website cooler), use CSS or bootstrap framework or whatsoever you wish.

So whenever you're between HTML or Something else, HTML is for 1st structure 2nd the meaning.